# Thymeleaf: Catch exception in controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have the below method in the controller that I catch an error inside it

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/popup")
public class PopupResource {

    @GetMapping
    public String popup() {
        try {
             service.generate(new ExistOTPValidQuery().requestNumber("test"), Boolean.class).get();
        } catch (OTPException e) {
              return "user";
        }
        return "error";
    }
}
```

I defined the exception

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice()
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(OTPException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> otpException(OTPException ex) {
        return buildResponseEntity(new ApiError(CustomHttpStatus.OTP_REQUEST, new Date(), ex.getMessage()),
            HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<Object> buildResponseEntity(ApiError apiError, HttpStatus status) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, status);
    }
    
}
```

The problem when the service throws the exception `OTPException`, it's not catched in the controller

when I put a break point on this catch block, I get the values like in the picture below

```
catch (Exception e) {
  if (e instanceof OTPException) { //it does not enter here
      return "user";
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As your screenshot states the type of variable `e` is not an OTPException, but an ExecutionException.
The cause of ExecutionException is an OTPException.

Either change that `service.generate(...)` throws directly an OTPException (and does not wrap it into an ExectionException).
Or change the catch block in your controller to catch ExecutionException and check the cause of the catched exception.